# Does neshamah apply to more than humans?

Tags: spirit

Psalm 150:6 NASB20

> Everything that has breath shall praise the LORD. Praise the LORD!

In this Psalm, the word “breath” is translated from “*neshamah*” meaning the breath, life, or spirit, first seen in Genesis 2.7.

In the 24 instances of neshamah that we see, they’re all in reference to humans exclusively. *Ruach* and on the other hand are used to refer to humans and animals as well as life, wind, etc.

The choice of the word “everything” in Psalm 150 is interesting because it doesn’t say let every man or human that has breath (*neshamah*) praise God. And it could’ve. What is the purpose or significance of saying “everything” here as opposed to the word “man?” Notably, given that *neshamah* is only used in association with man?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to my concordances, the word נְשָׁמָה (neshamah) = "breath" occurs 23 times in the OT.  A few times it signifies the breath or air-breathing animals such as:

- Gen 7:22 - of all that was on the dry land, all in whose nostrils was the **breath** of the spirit of life, died. [This is talking about all animals that breath air.]
- Deut 20:16 - However, in the cities of the nations that the LORD your God is giving you as an inheritance, you must not leave alive anything that **breathes**. [This includes air-breathing animals such as sheep and cattle.]
- Josh 10:40 - So Joshua struck the whole land, the hill country and the Negeb and the lowland and the slopes, and all their kings. He left none remaining, but devoted to destruction all that **breathed**, just as the LORD God of Israel commanded.
- Josh 11:11 - And they struck with the sword all who were in it, devoting them to destruction; there was none left that **breathed**. And he burned Hazor with fire.
- Ps 150:6 - Let everything that has breath praise the LORD! Praise the LORD! [This clearly includes not only humans but also air-breathing animals.]

Thus, the expression, "all that breathed" (or similar) can clearly, in some places, include air-breathing animals.

Comment: Thanks for responding here. This is what I thought too until digging into it more.

The BLB concordance shows 24 instances and it's definitely translated as breath sometimes but breath to humans.

The distinction is picked up in the surrounding verses for each of these.

Comment: Genesis 7.21-23: Every living thing that moved on land perished—birds, livestock, wild animals, all the creatures that swarm over the earth, **and all mankind.** (22) Everything on dry land that had the breath of life (neshama ruach) in its nostrils died. Every living thing on the face of the earth was wiped out; people and animals and the creatures that move along the ground and the birds were wiped from the earth. Only Noah was left, and those with him in the ark.

It can be argued v22 simply continues the thought of v21 (ending w/ mankind). V23 summarizes to include both man and animals.

Comment: In Deut 20.16, the following verse clarifies the context to mean humans: (17) Completely destroy them—the Hittites, Amorites, Canaanites, Perizzites, Hivites and Jebusites—as the Lord your God has commanded you.

Comment: Josh 10.40 + 11.11 go together and while the account both mentions man and animal, the surrounding verses clarify who had neshamah. Specifically v14: _The Israelites carried off for themselves all the plunder and livestock of these cities, but all the people they put to the sword until they completely destroyed them, not sparing anyone that breathed (neshamah)._

Man or people at the end here is what the neshamah seems to be referring to. This is backed up by the idea that they took livestock with them. If they destroyed everything with neshamah including animals, this would read different.

Comment: Obviously, these can be debated by interpretation but I think it's fair to say that a legitimate case can be made that neshamah is actually not referring to animals here based on the surrounding verses and context. They're clearly jumping back and forth with references to man/animal. At very best, it's at least ambiguous. Ps 150.6 seems to be somewhat of an outlier from these others though IMO, in that they choose "everything" rather than "man" when talking about neshamah. Maybe it's simply a summary or play on words but notable and what I'm looking to bring some light to.

Answer (score 0):

[**Note**: I prepared the below answer but could not publish because I had some guests to attend to. Now most of my points are mentioned by the OP in his comments proving that an impartial study of the Scripture leads to the same conclusion. Nevertheless, I publish my answer.]

Somehow my preliminary study of “neshamah” shows that the OP could be right in his statement that neshamah is “in reference to humans exclusively.” That is, wherever this word is referring to breathing physical world, it refers to humans only.

**Explanation**

It begins at Genesis 2:7.

- **Genesis 2:7** – the neshamah of life is given to “man” and he “became a living soul”. Animals are not mentioned in connection with neshamah.
- **Genesis 7:22** – this is a continuation of verse 21 that says, ‘all flesh died...the fowl, and cattle, and beast... and **all mankind**. The 22nd verse is, in fact, a qualification of the “all mankind”: “all died in whose nostrils was the breath of life….”. Again, verse 23 begins with “every living thing... .”

Here, neshamah is connected with “all mankind” and is differentiated from the fowl, the cattle, the beast, etc.

- **Deuteronomy 20:16** – “you shall not keep any that breathes”. Again, this is in reference to people because the very next verse qualifies “any that breathes”. What/who are they? “the Hittites, and the Amorites, the Canaanites, and the Perizzites, the Hivites, and the Jebusites... so that **they may not teach you**... .”. This cannot include non-humans.

Here, again, “any that breathes” is identified as the Hittite people, the Amorite people, the Canaanite people, etc., who were able to “teach the Israelites” the idolatry and the related pagan rituals. Animals cannot do that.

The next three are in relation to Joshua which shows clearly that any who breathes is human as is clear in this verse:

- **Joshua 11:14** - “And the sons of Israel seized for themselves all the plunder of these cities, and **the livestock**. But they struck every human being by the mouth of the sword until they had destroyed them; they did not leave anyone breathing”.

It is very clear that the livestock kept alive is separated from the “anyone breathing” destroyed.

- **1 King 15:29**  – Baasha “struck all the house of Jeroboam; he did not leave Jeroboam any who breathed”. Here, too, Baasha struck all the people in the household of Jeroboam. But Baasha didn’t kill any cattle or animals.

**Psalms 150:6**

A literal translation would be: “All that doth breathe doth praise Jah! Praise ye Jah!” (YLT). "**Everything**" may not be an apt translation.

Since in all the above verses, the Scripture distinguishes between animals on one hand and neshamah on the other, it is clear **to me** that Psalms 150:6 is talking about all the humans who breathe must praise the LORD.

Animals are not meant in this.